# Dragging droppable into an iframe with sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

When attempting to create a `droppable` to drop items in a `sortable` in another `iframe`. I succeeded in creating the two independent frames and linking them, I get the following jQuery objects:

- **Sender** - The container from which the droppable originates from
- **Item** - The item being dragged
- **Receiver** - The target sortable container

The functionality to drag items from `droppable` to `sortable` is still missing, so I need to review and debug the JSFiddle to have this functionality working and optimize the code. All logic is in this one JS script.

Some of the problems have already been discussed here, but on the information alone I could not make it work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piglin/QVcp5/17/)

```
// Create the iframe
$('<iframe id="editor-iframe" name="editor-iframe" src="" style="width:100%;overflow:visible;scrolling="no" seamless="seamless">').appendTo('body');
var iframe = $("#editor-iframe").contents();
iframe.bind("change", function() {
  $("#editor-iframe").css({
    height: iframe.$("body").outerHeight()
  });
});

// Parameters for sortable
var sortableParameters = {
  connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
  placeholder: {
    element: function(currentItem) {
      return '<li></li>';
    },
    update: function(container, placeholder) {
      if ($(container.element[0]).hasClass('sortable-grid')) {
        placeholder.removeClass('highlight-vertical');
        placeholder.addClass('highlight-horizontal');
      } else if ($(container.element[0]).hasClass('sortable-row')) {
        placeholder.removeClass('highlight-horizontal');
        placeholder.addClass('highlight-vertical');
      }
      return;
    }
  },
  start: function(event, ui) {
    if (typeof sender != 'undefined') {
      if (sender.hasClass('items')) {
            receiver = $(this);
      }
      return;
    }
    sender = $(this);
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {},
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    item = $(ui.item);
    receiver = $(ui.item.parent());

    //Create wrapper around cells passed into new rows
    if (item.hasClass('sortable-cell') && receiver.hasClass('sortable-grid')) {
      item.wrap("<li class='sortable-table'><ul class='sortable-row connectedSortable ui-sortable'></ul></li>").parentElement.sortable(sortableParameters);
    }
  },
  iframeFix: true
}

// Called after done loading the iframe
$("#editor-iframe").on("load", function() {

  // Initialize draggable
  $('.items li').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      sender = $(event.target.parentElement);
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {},
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      item = $(event.target);

      //Create wrapper around cells passed into new rows
      if (item.hasClass('sortable-cell') && receiver.hasClass('sortable-grid')) {
        item.wrap("<li class='sortable-table'><ul class='sortable-row connectedSortable ui-sortable'></ul></li>").parent().sortable(sortableParameters);
      }
    },
    helper: 'clone',
    iframeFix: true,
    connectToSortable: $('#editor-iframe').contents().find('.sortable-grid, .sortable-row').sortable(sortableParameters), // Initialize sortable
  });
});

// Load content for iframe
$("#editor-iframe").attr("src", "http://fiddle.jshell.net/piglin/UAcC7/1848/show/light/");
```